# What can the problem be in my android studio app?

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, android-glide

I am using android studio to develop my application; AndroidX to be precise. I am getting an error caused by `diskcachestategy`. Please help me fix it

```
private Context context;
private List<MenuCategoryObject> categoryObject;

public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<MenuCategoryObject> categoryObject) {
    this.context = context;
    this.categoryObject = categoryObject;
}

@Override
public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_category_list, parent, false);
    return new CategoryViewHolder(layoutView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final MenuCategoryObject catObject = categoryObject.get(position);
    final int id = catObject.getMenu_id();
    holder.categoryName.setText(catObject.getMenu_name());

    // use Glide to download and display the category image.
    String serverImagePath = Helper.PUBLIC_FOLDER + catObject.getMenu_image();
    Glide.with(context).load(serverImagePath).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).fitCenter().override(300, 300).into(holder.categoryImage);

    holder.categoryImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent categoryIntent = new Intent(context, SingleMenuCategoryActivity.class);
            categoryIntent.putExtra("CATEGORY_NAME", catObject.getMenu_name());
            categoryIntent.putExtra("CATEGORY_ID", id);
            context.startActivity(categoryIntent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categoryObject.size();
}


public static int getResourseId(Context context, String pVariableName, String pResourcename, String pPackageName) throws RuntimeException {
    try {
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(pVariableName, pResourcename, pPackageName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error getting Resource ID.", e);
    }
}
```

}

I get an error that says:

```
error: cannot find symbol method diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Either you are copy-pasting the code from somewhere or else you havent defined that method.

Comment: Can you please describe the problem in detail and put what you have tried for that to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

add `com.bumptech.glide.load.engine. DiskCacheStrategy` into you imports block in start of java file.

Answer (score 0):

First check that have you added this dependency in your build.gradel:-

```
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

If yes then paste this line in your import statements of that class:-

```
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine. DiskCacheStrategy
```